# My symfony website is not working - The file "config.yml" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, config

My website is in production environment. My config file does exist and it says config_.yml does not exist.
I have cleared my cache using 
  `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
cache cleared successfully but I get this error on loading my website

```
FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118:
The file "config.yml" does not exist (in:[path]/app/config) in config.yml (which is being imported from "[path]/app/config/config_prod.yml").
in FileLoader.php line 118
at FileLoader->import('config.yml', null, false, '[path]/app/config/config_prod.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 130
at YamlFileLoader->parseImports(array('imports' => array(array('resource' => 'config.yml')), 'monolog' => array('handlers' => array('main' => array('type' => 'fingers_crossed', 'action_level' => 'error', 'handler' => 'nested'), 'nested' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), 'console' => array('type' => 'console')))), '[path]/app/config/config_prod.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 79
at YamlFileLoader->load('[path]/app/config/config_prod.yml', null) in DelegatingLoader.php line 45
at DelegatingLoader->load('[path]/app/config/config_prod.yml') in AppKernel.php line 54
at AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration(object(DelegatingLoader)) in Kernel.php line 570
at Kernel->buildContainer() in Kernel.php line 483
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 165
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app.php line 30
```

Then I figured out that all other pages of my website are working fine but this error shows on homepage. 
And my homepage also loads correctly with **www.** and withoug **www.** it shows this error. 
I don't know it's acting weird. Can anyone of you please help me in this? Now i am deleting the cache of prod environment manually **var/cache/prod**

Comment: Every new user that lands on my website gets this error.

Comment: is `[path]` correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what `[path]` is here? Prefix of absolute path?

Comment: For some reason your "homepage" is trying to rebuild the cache.  You always have to manually rebuild it after making changes to the site.  Don't know what else would be causing it.